# What is the effect of K in K-NN on the VC dimension?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, computational-learning-theory, vc-dimension, k-nearest-neighbors

What is the effect of K in K-NN on the VC dimension? When K increases, is the VC dimension decreased or increased, or we can't say anything about this? Is there a reference book that discusses this?